# SQL Server Gender Swap Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table having the following column:

```
ID, Name, Designation, Salary, Contact, Address, Gender
```

Accidentally for all male Gender i have entered 'Female' and similarly for all Female gender i have entered 'Male'. For Exmaple

```
0023 Scott Developer 15000 4569865 Cliff_Eddington,USA Female
```

I the above line There should be Male instead of female. And there are all Male whose gender has been updated as Female. Same case for all Female Gender has been updated as Male.

Is there any Single query through which i can change all the Rows whose Gender is Male Change it to Female and All the Rows whose Gender is Female Change it to Male.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would run a `SELECT COUNT(*)` before running the updates so that you get the correct results and then `COMMIT` the transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE tableA 
   SET Gender = CASE  
                WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 'Female'  
                ELSE 'Male'  
                END

--COMMIT TRANSACTION
--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 9):

this should do it

```
UPDATE tbl SET Gender = (CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 'Female' ELSE 'Male' END)
```

(sorry, was mysql syntax, fixed for ms-sql)

Comment: there are no backticks in sqlserver

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Gendeer =   CASE 
                    WHEN Gender = 'Male' 
                        THEN 'Female' 
                    ELSE 'Male' 
                END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a generic way of doing it, you can also use below queries. I will not say this method is faster or simpler but it would be generic to all relational databases. I came here to findout a query without DECODE and CASE statements and found this answer. So thought of sharing this.

`UPDATE tableA SET Gender = 'Temp' WHERE Gender = 'Male';

 UPDATE tableA SET Gender = 'Male' WHERE Gender = 'Female';
 UPDATE tableA SET Gender = 'Female' WHERE Gender = 'Temp';`

Answer (score 0):

1) First Method

```
Update *Table_Name*
Set *Column_Name* = Case *Column_Name*
When 'M' then 'F' 
When 'F' then 'M'
End
```

2) Second Method

```
Update *Table_Name*
Set *Column_Name* = IF('M','F','M')
```

- Not Pretty much sure about the 2) but 1) works.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE CORRECT ONE.

```
 UPDATE dbo.EmpGender
    SET Gender = (CASE
        WHEN Gender = 'MALE' THEN 'FEMALE' ELSE 'MALE'
    END)

IF YOU DONT WANT TO USE CASE STATEMENT THEN.



 UPDATE dbo.EmpGender
SET Gender = REPLACE(('fe'+Gender),'fefe','')

IN SQL 2012 YOU CAN USE
UPDATE dbo.EmpGender
SET Gender = IIF(Gender = 'male', 'female', 'male')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE GENDER(TABLE NAME)
SET GENDER(COLUMN NAME) = CASE WHEN GENDER(COLUMNNAME)='MALE'
                                   THEN 'FEMALE'
                               ELSE 'MALE'
                          END;
```

Here my table name and column name are same so it is clearly specified in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old thread, it should be a bit faster to use IF to swap gender compared to CASE WHEN:

```
UPDATE table
   SET Gender = IF(GENDER='Male','Female','Male');
```

Comment: I believe you meant `IIF`. It's not faster then `CASE` either and it's only available starting from SQL Server 2012.